# What's Kotlin Backing Field For?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

As a Java developer, the concept of a backing field is a bit foreign to me. Given:

```
class Sample {
    var counter = 0 // the initializer value is written directly to the backing field
    set(value) {
        if (value >= 0) field = value
    }
}
```

What's this backing field good for? [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) said:

> *Classes in Kotlin cannot have fields. However, sometimes it is necessary to have a backing field when using custom accessors*.

Why? What's the difference with using the properties name itself inside the setter, eg.*

```
class Sample {        
    var counter = 0
    set(value) {
        if (value >= 0) this.counter = value // or just counter = value?
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the property itself in the setter will result in an endless recursion since assigning some value to the property will always call the setter.

Comment: @Strelok my bad.... I was assuming that `this.counter = value` is the same with the Java equivalent when reading Kotlin's docs.

Comment: This [article](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-field-vs-property-30ab7ef70531) is for  Field vs Property.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Because, say if you don't have `field` keyword, you won't be able to actually set/get the value in the `get()` or `set(value)`. It enables you to access the backing field in the custom accessors.

This is the equivalent Java code of your sample:

```
class Sample {
    private int counter = 0;
    public void setCounter(int value) {
        if (value >= 0) setCounter(value);
    }
    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Apparently this is not good, as the setter is just an infinte recursion into itself, never changing anything. Remember in kotlin whenever you write `foo.bar = value` it will be translated into a setter call instead of a `PUTFIELD`.

---

EDIT: Java has *fields* while Kotlin has *properties*, which is a rather higher level concept than fields.

There are two types of properties: one with a backing field, one without.

A property with a backing field will store the value in the form of a field. That field makes storing value in memory possible. An example of such property is the `first` and `second` properties of `Pair`. That property will change the in-memory representation of `Pair`.

A property without a backing field will have to store their value in other ways than directly storing it in memory. It must be computed from other properties, or, the object itself. An example of such property is the `indices` extension property of `List`, which is not backed by a field, but a computed result based on `size` property. So it won't change the in-memory representation of `List` (which it can't do at all because Java is statically typed).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My bad... I was assuming that `this.counter = value` is the same with java equivalent.

Comment: Anywhere documented? Thanks:)

Comment: @Alston, here is the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

Comment: A lot of fuzzy explanations. Why can't we just plainly say, that a `field` is more like a pointer or a reference to an existing member variable.  Since the `get/set` immediately followes `counter` therefore, the `field` keyword is a reference to `counter`.  Right?

Comment: @typelogic this answer is most tailored for programmers with Java/JS backgrounds (back then there is no Kotlin/Native), not C/C++. What you find fuzzy is bread and butter for some other people.

Comment: this is actually way better and easier explanation rather than in the official documentation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 49):

Initially, I too had a tough time understanding this concept. So let me explain it to you with the help of an example.

Consider this Kotlin class

```
class DummyClass {
    var size = 0;
    var isEmpty
        get() = size == 0
        set(value) {
            size = size * 2
        }
}
```

Now when we look at the code, we can see that it has 2 properties i.e - `size` (with default accessors) and `isEmpty`(with custom accessors). But it has only 1 field i.e. `size`. To understand that it has only 1 field, let us see the Java equivalent of this class.

Go to Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin ByteCode in Android Studio. Click on Decompile.

```
   public final class DummyClass {
   private int size;

   public final int getSize() {
      return this.size;
   }

   public final void setSize(int var1) {
      this.size = var1;
   }

   public final boolean isEmpty() {
      return this.size == 0;
   }

   public final void setEmpty(boolean value) {
      this.size *= 2;
   }
}
```

Clearly we can see that the java class has only getter and setter functions for `isEmpty`, and there is no field declared for it. Similarly in Kotlin, there is no backing field for property `isEmpty`, since the property doesn't depend on that field at all. Thus no backing field.

---

Now let us remove the custom getter and setter of `isEmpty` property.

```
class DummyClass {
    var size = 0;
    var isEmpty = false
}
```

And the Java equivalent of the above class is

```
public final class DummyClass {
   private int size;
   private boolean isEmpty;

   public final int getSize() {
      return this.size;
   }

   public final void setSize(int var1) {
      this.size = var1;
   }

   public final boolean isEmpty() {
      return this.isEmpty;
   }

   public final void setEmpty(boolean var1) {
      this.isEmpty = var1;
   }
}
```

Here we see both the fields `size` and `isEmpty`. `isEmpty` is a backing field because the getter and setter for `isEmpty` property depend upon it.

Comment: Good explanation. Thank you

Comment: Really, thanks for the explanation. I've come to Kotlin from Java, too, and the concept of *properties* is new to me. But I've understood it, thanks to you and guides. :)

Comment: God may bless you.

Comment: I like this answer it is honestly cited the facts. I'm still in doubt, because **C#** has no need for `field` keyword is it possible that a language improvement of Kotlin will remove this weird `field` keyword and avoid the helpless souls from falling into the abyss of infinite recursion?

Answer (score 11):

Backing fields are good for running validation or triggering events on state change. Think of the times you've added code to a Java setter/getter. Backing fields would be useful in similar scenarios. You would use backing fields when you needed to control or have visibility over setters/getters.

When assigning the field with the field name itself, you're actually invoking the setter (i.e. `set(value)`). In the example you have, `this.counter = value` would recurse into set(value) until we overflow our stack. Using `field` bypasses the setter (or getter) code.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation contains the term that needs to be explained. And then, you first cited a Java scenario and then suddenly without warning you switch lains to an actual Kotlin statement. The Kotlin need for the keyword `field` is not in **C#** so we need a better explanation than the one you cited here.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is using **field** identifier as a reference to the property's value in **get** or **set**, when you want to change or use the property's value in **get** or **set**.

For example:

```
class A{
    var a:Int=1
        get(){return field * 2}    // Similiar to Java: public int geta(){return this.a * 2}
        set(value) {field = value + 1}
}
```

Then:

```
var t = A()
println(t.a)    // OUTPUT: 2, equal to Java code: println(t.a * 2)
t.a = 2         // The real action is similar to Java code: t.a = t.a +1
println(t.a)    // OUTPUT: 6, equal to Java code: println(t.a * 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The terminology `backing field` is filled with mystery. The keyword used is `field`. The `get/set` methods, follows immediately next to the member variable that is about to be *get* or *set* through this door protective methods mechanism. The `field` keyword just refers to the member variable that is to be *set* or *get*. At present Kotlin, you cannot refer to the member variable directly inside the *get* or *set* protective door methods because it will unfortunately result to infinite recursion because it will re-invoke the *get* or *set* and thus leds the runtime down into the deep abyss.

In **C#** though, you can directly reference the member variable inside the getter/setter methods. I am citing this comparison to present the idea that this `field` keyword is how the present Kotlin is implementing it but I do hope it will be removed in later versions and allow us to directly reference the member variable directly without resulting to infinite recursion.