# `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when accessing Kotlin property

Tags: kotlin

I got this (contrived) sample from Packt's "Programming Kotlin" on using secondary constructor with inheritance.

> Edit: from the answer it is clear that the issue is about [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields). But the book did not introduced that idea, just with the wrong  example.

```
open class Payment(val amount: Int) 

class ChequePayment : Payment { 
    constructor(amount: Int, name: String, bankId: String) :  super(amount) { 
        this.name = name
        this.bankId = bankId 
    }

    var name: String
        get() = this.name
    var bankId: String
        get()  = this.bankId
} 


val c = ChequePayment(3, "me", "ABC")    
println("${c} ${c.amount} ${c.name}")
```

When I run it this error is shown.

```
$ kotlinc -script class.kts 2>&1 | more
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Class$ChequePayment.getName(class.kts:10)
    at Class$ChequePayment.getName(class.kts:10)
    at Class$ChequePayment.getName(class.kts:10)
```

Line 10 does seems to be a infinite recursion, how to solve it?

Comment: too bad that Packt's material contain non-working examples

Comment: Ouch. That's not a good sign... additionally, I know this is for the purpose of an example, but you probably would use a primary constructor for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's Kotlin Backing Field For?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220140/whats-kotlin-backing-field-for)

Comment: Kinda, but the error is cryptic for a newbie not familiar with the idea of field keyword (or the property instead of field in Kotlin). The links does helps clarify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the backing field you have to use the keyword `field` instead of `this.name` see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

`this.name` references the getter, which references `this.name` which is an infinite recursion, as you already noted. In code:

```
var name: String
    get() = field
var bankId: String
    get()  = field
```

Side note: Android Studio and Idea will complain rightfully that you don't need a getter in this case. So you can simplify even more:

```
var name: String
var bankId: String
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a recursion in your code:

```
class ChequePayment : Payment { 
    constructor(amount: Int, name: String, bankId: String) :  super(amount) { 
        this.name = name
        this.bankId = bankId 
    }

    var name: String
        get() = this.name // recursion: will invoke getter of name (itself)
    var bankId: String
        get()  = this.bankId // recursion: will invoke getter of bankId (itself)
}
```

If you don't need custom logic for your getter, just leave your properties like this:

```
var name: String
var bankId: String
```

They will have a default getter, which does nothing more than returning the value of the backing field.

**Note:** The code as it is can/should be refactored to this:

```
class ChequePayment(amount: Int, var name: String, var bankId: String) : Payment(amount) {
    // ...
}
```

This uses the primary constructor and is much less redundant.